# Xcode Swift Firebase real-time database is not updated

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wrote a method in XCode to save a "user" in my firebase real-time database. Unfortunately, the data is not displayed in my real-time database in my browser, although I got the feedback from Xcode through my built-in print command that everything went well.
Does somebody have any idea?
I would be really happy to hear from you.
Best wishes

PS: Yes: read and write are activated in my database rules.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What does the Firestore document say?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer. 1. This is about the real-time database and not about the firestore. 2. There is nothing in the documetation about my problem. Best regards

Comment: Find the doc for yourself, then, like https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data

Comment: Not an answer, but it might help to add a completion block to `setValue` so that in case of an error, you would be able to see/print it.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android we've been seeing some issues with reading the configuration file for databases in non-default locations, like yours being in Europe here.

I'm not sure if that is the problem here, but it might be worth passing the URL for the database in code:

```
let ref = Database.database("URL of your database here")...
```